# Why am I getting 403 forbidden when I try to validate JWT from Zuul Proxy?

Tags: java, jwt, netflix-zuul

I have registered authentication-service on Eureka and authenticating using Zuul proxy. This the application.properties file of the Zuul service:

```
server.port=8090
zuul.routes.authentication-service.url=http://localhost:8095
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
zuul.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

http://localhost:8095/login is mapped for authentication and http://localhost:8095/validate for validating the token. Because of zuul proxy, I can access those resources from http://localhost:8090/authentication-service/. The `/login` mapping is working fine but when I try http://localhost:8090/authentication-service/validate and pass the token in "Authorization", I get "Access Denied". This is what I have in Postman:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-18T09:30:35.543+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/validate"
}
```

But when I pass the same token http://localhost:8095/validate, I get the desired result.

What am I missing here? Was there an issue passing token from Zuul? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `Authorization` in your `sensitive-headers` configuration.

Zuul automatically remove headers specified in sensitive headers.
So your token is removed from your request.